# Why are External JS files added in html file not working when using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am currently working on a react application and everything was working fine until recently when I noticed that all the external scripts I defined in the public/html no longer works when rendering pages using react-router-dom, but works fine when I call the pages directly.

These is my html file body tag:

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/plugins.bundle.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/intro.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/widgets.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/chat.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      defer
      type="text/javascript"
      src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/js/modals/create-app.js"
    ></script>
  </body>
```

Everthing works perfectly if I render the page this way:

```
const App = () => {
  
  return (
  <UserDashboard/>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But when using react-router-dom, it doesnt throw any errors but nothing works

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<UserDashboard />/>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

My folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

Please does anyone know why this is happening and how can I fix it, cause I'm using a template and those scripts are necessary for the template to function properly.

I'm beginning to think this has to with react-router-dom version 6, cause I have not encountered this problem when working on previous projects. Its the only thing I can suspect would downgrading the react-router-dom be a bad idea?

Comment: It's probably because when your scripts run there is no DOM initialized. I had same issue. Put some of the functionality in `setTimeout` and it worked most of the time. Dirty, bad solution but still a solution. Also try putting your scripts after body or add `defer` attribute.

Comment: How do I put some of the functionality in setTimeout, do you mean in the js files or my react application

Comment: I mean non-react js scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I needed to load scripts in html tags in an app created from create-react-app library and found that I needed to put them in the `body`, afer `root`and use the `defer`keyword as below:

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
<script defer type='text/javascript' src='%PUBLIC_URL%/ccapture/CCapture.js'></script>
    <script defer type='text/javascript' src='%PUBLIC_URL%/ccapture/gif.js'></script>
    <script defer type='text/javascript' src='%PUBLIC_URL%/ccapture/webm-writer-0.3.0.js'></script>
    <script defer type='text/javascript' src='%PUBLIC_URL%/ccapture/download.js'></script>
```

Can't remember if using the `%PUBLIC_URL%` variable was part of the solution or I just used it because the template had similar.

Comment: Added it like you suggested, its still not working

Comment: Can you add to your question as much of the index.html file as you can and a description of your folder structure?

Comment: I made the changes like you suggested, this is really furstrating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The script paths are relative to the current URL path. They probably work without issue if/when the app loads and you are on the root `"/"` route, but have issue when on any sub-route.

Specify absolute paths in your public directory instead.

```
<script src="/assets/js/plugins.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/intro.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/widgets.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/chat.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/modals/create-app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I'm using Electron with webpack and was able to resolve this by adding a custom file protocol to handle custom requests for static files. Added within the window creation handler. This may be of help.

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, session } from 'electron';
//...
session.defaultSession.protocol.registerFileProtocol('asset', (request, callback) => {
        const fileUrl = request.url.replace('asset://', '');
        const filePath = path.join(app.getAppPath(), '.webpack/assets', fileUrl);
        callback(filePath);
    });
```